# How to set an expiry date for an object in django?

Tags: django

I am making a django app that shows routine orders for a college website. A particular order should remain for a week on the website and then disappear. This is my model.

```
class RoutineOrder(models.Model):
    Subject = models.TextField()
    Details = RichTextUploadingField()
    LastEdited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    Added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('nitwro:home')
```

```
class Home(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'nitwro/home.djt'
   startdate = datetime.today()
   enddate = startdate + timedelta(days=6)
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
           context = super(Home, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
           context['allorders'] = RoutineOrder.objects.filter().order_by('-Added')
        return context
```

What to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Filter your objects passed to the view to only those created in the past week;

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

past_week = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=7)
objects = RoutineOrder.objects.filter(added__gte=past_week)
```

It's also good practice to have lowercase field names.

Comment: OOPS got it. Late night mistakes :)

Comment: @SapnaSharma i did this...
class Home(TemplateView):

          template_name = 'college/home.djt'

          past_week = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=7)

          def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

                  context = super(Home, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

                  context['allorders'] = 
RoutineOrder.objects.filter(added__gte=past_week)).order_by('-Added')

                  return context


where am i wrong. this is giving syntax error

Comment: @ShashwatShukla the syntax error is two braces after `past_week))`. That says `RoutineOrder.objects.filter(added__gte=past_week)).order_by('-Added')` so has an extra closing brace.